# How do I train a neural network capable of calculating XOR using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying to train a simple feedforward network using MATLAB. It computes XOR. Here's my code:

```
net = feedforwardnet([3]);
P = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1]';
T = [0 1 1 0]; % desired output
net = configure(net, P, T);
net.trainParam.goal = 1e-8;
net.trainParam.epochs = 1000;
net = train(net, P, T);
```

It says that the goal is met. However, I don't get the desired output:

```
sim(net, P)

1.4885    0.6830    0.7796    0.3879
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need more training examples. Repeat some of them.

In my case I tried:

```
net = feedforwardnet([3]);
%Repeat 4 times
P = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1; 0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1; 0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1; 0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1]';
T = [0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]; % desired output
net = configure(net, P, T);
net.trainParam.goal = 1e-8;
net.trainParam.epochs = 1000;
net = train(net, P, T);
```

And the result is

```
 sim(net, P)

ans =
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.0000    0.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.0000
  Columns 9 through 16
    0.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.0000    0.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.0000
```

Comment: Yeah. At the end I did that. But I still have some doubts:

1) Isn't a epoch basically one iteration? I thought that when I defined epochs = 1000 I was saying "look, use `P` and `T` to train the network `net` and repeat the process another 999 if it's needed".

2) I'm kind of used to Encog (Java Framework) and i like to write the code [like this](http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Hello_World).Is it possible in MATLAB to get the current error?

Comment: @user3680 Yeah, epoch is that, but you tell the NN the MAXIMUM epoch, if he achieves the accuracy faster it will stop, why do 1000 epoch if in 1 epoch the output is correct? you said it: "If it's needed". Sorry, I dont know java, nor Encog....

Comment: @user3680 BTW, if the answer has helped you mark is as correct please ;)